# How to control the width of jquery mobile select menu header based on selected option

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.2.0 Alpha for my web app. I am using JQM select drop-down menu for populating timezone option list. For small option text JQM adjusting the select menu header as well as other fields width according to the device screen size. But for large option text, select menu header becomes too wide and it going beyond the screen size and it spoiling other fields width also.

I tried setting min-width and max-width to select menu header, but it not working. I added screen shot here for reference.

```
<select id="TimeZoneId" name="TimeZoneId" data-mini="true">
```

[image: JQM select menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the target element, and add this to your CSS file:

```
#TimeZoneId {
     white-space:normal !important
}
```

This should make the text wrap

Comment: Ya i tried that, but in jquery mobile, by directly adding white-space in target element its not working. but by wrapping it in div and using that id, its working. I fixed it by adding this $('#dropdown-list').find('span').each(function () { $(this).css("white-space", "normal"); });

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but this will also fix the word-wrapping. (jQuery Mobile version 1.4.3)

**CSS:**

```
.ui-select .ui-btn>span:not(.ui-li-count) {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```